# How to pass a calculated file name back to the UI in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny server I am figuring out the name of a markdown file which I want to show in the UI.  I know how to pass the file name, as a string, back to the UI but I don't now how to tell `includeMarkdown()` to treat the string as a file name.

My code so far is below.  Any advice?

```
library(shiny)

fileConn<-file("hello.md")
writeLines(c("# Hello","# World"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)


ui <- fluidPage(
    includeMarkdown("hello.md"),
    br(),
    div("File name text:", textOutput("fileNameText", inline = TRUE)),
    #includeMarkdown(fileNameText) # this needs help
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    selectedName <- reactive({
            paste0("hello.md") # this is actually more complicated...
    })
    
    output$fileNameText <- renderText(
        paste0(selectedName())
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The code you provided seems to work - can you provide an example that showcases your problem?  I take it you want a way to "select" the file and pass it to `includeMarkdown()`?  Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the calculated string (which I hard coded in the example) into `includeMarkdown()`.

Comment: Gotcha - answer incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code works fine, but from your description, I am thinking your asking how to pass a different filename to `includeMarkdown()` that was created somewhere else in the app, correct?

The first step is to understand `includeMarkdown()` as a UI element that will change depending on other UI elements (and stuff that happens in `server`).  The solution is to use a placeholder in the `ui` to hold the place for the `includeMarkdown()` element, and create that particular element in `server` using `renderUI`.

Hopefully you can follow this example.  I'm using `uiOutput('displayFile')` to hold the place for the element that's created in server.

```
library(shiny)

fileConn<-file("hello.md")
writeLines(c("# Hello","# World"), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
    
fileConn1<-file("goodbye.md")
writeLines(c("# Goodbye","# Everyone!"), fileConn1)
close(fileConn1)
    
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('file_selection', 'Choose Markdown File:', choices=c('hello.md','goodbye.md')),
  uiOutput('displayFile')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$displayFile <- renderUI({
    includeMarkdown(input$file_selection)
  })      
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The trick I needed was:
 output$displayFile <- renderUI({
  includeMarkdown(selectedName())
 })  
along with the uiOutput().  You just made my day!

Comment: Yep.  That's the important bit.  Once you understand how you can create UI elements in server and pass them back to ui, it really changes how you think of shiny apps.  You can do similar things using [conditional panels](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/conditionalPanel.html).  You can read up on [creating dynamic UI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) here for more information.